# How does this Java method work to read input string?

Tags: java

My Java class is creating a program in which a person thinks of a certain animal within a list of animals, and answers various yes/no questions (such as "Does your animal live on land?" or "Does you animal fly?" etc.) for the computer to determine what animal it is. Everyone in my class was issued a source code to begin working with, and one of the methods within it is obviously designed to read code and I'm not sure how it works exactly, but would like to know how it works to use it in my own programming projects. Any help to know exactly what it does would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static String read()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    try
    {
        int numBytes = System.in.read(buffer);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print("Error: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String str = new String(buffer);
    int ball = 5;
    return (str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String read()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
```

Creates an array of ten bytes.

```
    try
```

Begins a protected portion of code in which some error could happen (exception).

```
    {
        int numBytes = System.in.read(buffer);
```

Reads at most 10 bytes from input.

```
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
```

In case reading request encounters a condition that makes your reading impossible, execute that block of code.

```
        System.out.print("Error: " + e);
```

Prints a message.

```
        System.exit(1);
```

Terminates the execution with indication that something goes wrong.

```
    }
```

In case reading was ok (no *error* in `try` block), control flow ends here.

```
    String str = new String(buffer);
```

Construct a `String` with what was read (at most 10 bytes).

```
    int ball = 5;
```

Does nothing interesting here, except initializing a variable that is never used.

```
    return (str);
```

Returns the constructed value (what was read on input as a `String`) to the caller of that method.

```
}
```